# Lazy load with multi level objects from Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, lazy-loading

I have ClassRoom and User class:

```
@Entity
public class ClassRoom {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> users;
    // etc
}

@Entity
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Role> roles;
    // etc
}
```

With a one-to-many relation that is lazy.

I am trying to fetch ClassRoom with users and their roles so in DAO :-

> @Query("SELECT cr FROM ClassRoom as cr join fetch cr.users u ")

But with that  query i am getting classRoom with its users but not with their roles. Please suggest right way to fetch Users with roles from classroom class.

Comment: If you're using Spring Data, you can use `@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"users", "users.roles"})` instead of `@Query`, and you'll have to remap you entities to use `Set` instead of `List`, or you'll get `MultipleBagFetchException`. Otherwise, maybe [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-multi-level-fetching/) can help you.

Comment: @StefanGolubović sounds good that there is an solution for this issue. Yes I am using spring data 4.1 and JPA 1.7 and hibernate 4.3.6. with that i am not able to import EntityGraph(attributePaths. Please suggest ..

Comment: seems like `@EntityGraph` annotation is introduced in JPA 2.1, so I guess you'll have to use some other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch roles:

@Query("SELECT cr FROM ClassRoom cr join fetch cr.users u join fetch u.roles r")